# install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 for PyAthenaJDBC

Tags: python, visual-c++, pycharm

I get this error message:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.
```

When I try to install [PyAthenaJDBC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAthenaJDBC/). I am pretty sure it is installed. Is there a way to check that it is installed and if it installed maybe I have to specify to path for it for Python/PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had to install the old VS Studio 2015 Express